# How to minimize the eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix?

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I have a complex hermitian matrix, M[x_,y_] whose eigenvalues must be real.I tried to minimize the first eigenvalue by writing following command:f[x_,y_]:=Eigenvalues[M[x,y]][[1]];
Minimize[f[x,y],{x,y}]

But the error shows:
Minimize::The objective function f[x,y]  contains a nonreal constant -I.
Can somebody kindly solve my problem?

Comment: Without knowing the matrix `M` it's difficult to debug this. At the very least you should constrain the patterns on `f`: `f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := ...`. This ensures the eigenvalues only get evaluated for numeric inputs. You should also ensure that the returned value of `f` is always real. The appropriate function for minimizing this problem is `NMinimize`. Finally, you probably want to use `First @ Eigenvalues[M[x,y], 1]` to make sure `Eigenvalues` only computes the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Hamiltonian is: H[ a_, x_]: = {{0., -Exp[I*(a + x)], -Exp[I*x] - 1, Exp[I*a]},{-Exp[-I*(a + x)], 0., Exp[I*a], -Exp[I*x] - 1},{-Exp[-I*x] - 1, Exp[-I*a], 0., -Exp[I*(a - x)]},{Exp[-I*a], -Exp[-I*x] - 1, -Exp[-I*(a - x)], 0.}} ; The NMinimize works fine. Thanks.